# kitkat is not letting me upload images

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat

I currently am using the default "file choose/image picker" in android to select the image i want to  upload to my server. But the file chooser is not working with android kitkat. When ever I choose an image using the file chooser the URI or the local address to my image is returned as NULL. My code works perfectly with other android devices starting from android 2.2/2.3 to 4.2/4.3.

What I would love to know is if there is a way around it or is there a custom file chooser or a script that i should be using?

Any help is appreciated since this is my first time on stackoverflow. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

never mind I found it.

```
Bitmap bitmap;

private static final int READ_REQUEST_CODE = 42;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

// Filter to only show results that can be "opened", such as a
// file (as opposed to a list of contacts or timezones)
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

// Filter to show only images, using the image MIME data type.
// If one wanted to search for ogg vorbis files, the type would be "audio/ogg".
// To search for all documents available via installed storage providers,
// it would be "*/*".
 intent.setType("image/*");

 startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);

    }


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
    Intent resultData) {

// The ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent was sent with the request code
// READ_REQUEST_CODE. If the request code seen here doesn't match, it's the
// response to some other intent, and the code below shouldn't run at all.

 if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    // The document selected by the user won't be returned in the intent.
    // Instead, a URI to that document will be contained in the return intent
    // provided to this method as a parameter.
    // Pull that URI using resultData.getData().
     Uri uri = null;
     if (resultData != null) {
         uri = resultData.getData();

        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),uri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         ImageView my_img_view = (ImageView ) findViewById (R.id.uploadlayout2);
         my_img_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);                                        
    }
 }
 }
```

this worked for me.
Just remove the last lines about declaring a string and toasting the uri. And you are good to go.